# Why am I getting "Unexpected token (" here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Apologies if this is a type-o that I'm having trouble seeing. My browser (Chrome) is calling attention to the following line

```
<a class="carousel-link" onclick="function(){jQuery('#coffee-modal').modal('show');}">Book a coffee</a>
```

and saying

> "Unexpected token ("

but I can't see any mismatch in paranthesis. I know it's  isolated to this line because the error goes away if I remove it.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's causing an error, but that code won't work as intended: the code in the `onclick` attribute is executed directly. It's not evaluated as a function which is then executed. If you get rid of the `function(){ ... }` it will probably work.

Comment: `$(".carousel-link").on('click',function(){jQuery('#coffee-modal').modal('show');});` NOT in the markup would be SO much better than in-line code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `onclick` attribute will implicitly (try to) create a function that if explicitly declared would look like:

```
function something() {
  function() {jQuery('#coffee-modal').modal('show');}
}
```

Because the `function` keyword appears at the beginning of the implied first statement of the implied function, the parser expects the function to be named. The `(` is encountered before a name, so blammo.

I think the `function() { ... }` wrapper you've got is almost certainly the source of the confusion. You don't need it; that's implicitly supplied by the browser for `onfoo` attributes.

Comment: Blah. I hate having to write extra functions for a single use case.

Comment: ?? You don't have to write extra functions, @SubparWebDev. The point is that all you need in the `onclick` attribute value is the jQuery call. However, you'd really be much better off binding the handler with jQuery in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better if you avoid `inline-events`. Try:

```
<a class="carousel-link">Book a coffee</a>
```

```
$('body').on('click', '.carousel-link', function(){
    jQuery('#coffee-modal').modal('show');
})
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That may be your preference, but it doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Thanks @squint for you comment, i think that will solve the problem in OP.